# Three.js / WebGL Loading Large Amounts of Texture Data at Once, How To?

Tags: javascript, memory, three.js, webgl

Recently I had a project where I needed to create a lot of large textures using canvas and then upload them to the GPU. I was constantly running out of memory (chrome was crashing) and "choking" when the page loaded since all the textures were being pushed through the GPU bus at once.

I decided to stagger the `texture.needsUpdate = true;` calls so that all the textures are not pushed to the GPU in a single render update.

This works, but I'm curious of any other solutions...

I posted this because it might be helpful to others who are loading all their textures at launch...

Comment: I have a similar problem. I load about 50MB of jpeg data which is large I admit, but memory starts being consumed, and ends up using over 8GB of RAM. I have pinpointed the textures as the issue. They are being loaded from the JSON loader.

Comment: Check out this post on using compressed textures, will explain why your JPGs are blowing up as well: http://blog.tojicode.com/2011/12/compressed-textures-in-webgl.html

Comment: I will add something I discovered. It uses the same texture map on 2 or more materials (different shading properties). The JSON loader loads them as a separate texture each time, instead of loading 1 texture per file (it should combine based on file name which could be considered a bug or feature request).

Answer (score 1):

Culling textures down to nothing is the best way to stop excessive load. Making them smaller at the root will improve everything that follows down the line.

*While this post is old, It appears as a top result on google. So here are some handy hints for any other beginner 3D game/web developers.*

Textures are added to the buffer in fixed bit chunks, the less chunks the better, but creating your textures at the resolution of the power of two will prevent half chunks being loaded and wasting bits/time. Power of refers to a sequence of numbers that are doubled at each instance (2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64), keeping to this formula will prevent lost bits.

Look at the size of your texture on screen. Your source may be 1024x1024 but if it is only ever 20px high on the screen or your output canvas id 480x640 all that extra info is lost. Reduce you textures down to match what they are on screen.

In that same regard take out colors on your textures if you're not using them, sometime you can use vertex coloring and/or lights to add back detail to your texture in which case save you texture as a greyscale image, or limit the palette size by indexing them.

.gif is a great format for small textures, whil Jpeg is better for compressing large ones. If you using .gif you can also save space by grouping your textures on one image and palette matching them. Remember the entire Zelda LTTP game ran off 256 colors only. There are ways of creating a RGB index array and storing images as raw numbers that pull from it.

If you are importing/exporting from JSON remember that your images default to raw 32bit .png files. Which in themselves are large, becoming even larger when added as bit data to the end of a JSON objet file. 
Exporting just the mesh data and adding the texture back to it via JS in your source allows you to use more formats and optimize more of your textures.

Comment: This isn't really addressing the question, but rather suggesting we don't have large textures in the first place. While I appreciate your detail, I am aware of the ins and outs of how bits and bytes work. The fact remains is they must be sent to VRAM at some point and I'm curious how different users avoid flooding the buffer and crashing their pages, which is a typical scenario if all textures are sent at once.